# How to make my code statements appear in one line with clang-format?

Tags: c++, clang, visual-studio-code, clang-format

I created a .clang-format but I can not find the line that is causing this issue. I want the individual statements to be on individual lines even if they are long, and not break them into multilines. I tried to increase the *ColumnLimit* to 150 still unable to get the desired formatting.

I am trying my code to look like this(In one line)-

```
std::cout << "Congratulations, you sorted the list.\n" << "You needed " << score << " reversals." << std::endl;
```

```
std::vector<uint32_t> returnVector(uint32_t *LongNameForParameter1, double *LongNameForParameter2, const float &LongNameForParameter3,const std::map<std::string, int32_t> &LongNameForParameter4)
```

However using this .clang-format it is looking like this

```
std::cout << "Congratulations, you sorted the list.\n"
              << "You needed " << score << " reversals." << std::endl;
```

```
std::vector<uint32_t> returnVector(uint32_t *LongNameForParameter1, double *LongNameForParameter2, const float &LongNameForParameter3,
                                           const std::map<std::string, int32_t> &LongNameForParameter4)
```

**My .clang-format**

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: '-2'
AlignConsecutiveMacros: 'true'
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: 'true'
AlignTrailingComments: 'true'
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: 'false'
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: 'false'
BreakBeforeBraces: Stroustrup
ColumnLimit: '150'
CompactNamespaces: 'false'
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
IndentCaseLabels: 'true'
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentWidth: '4'
Language: Cpp
NamespaceIndentation: All
ReflowComments: 'true'
SortIncludes: 'true'
SortUsingDeclarations: 'true'
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: 'true'
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: 'false'
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: 'true'
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: 'true'
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: 'true'
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: 'true'
SpaceBeforeParens: Never
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: 'false'
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: 'true'
SpacesInAngles: 'false'
SpacesInParentheses: 'false'
SpacesInSquareBrackets: 'false'
Standard: Auto
TabWidth: '4'
```

Comment: why do you want this? Long lines are extremely unreadable and most importantly they make the whole file extremely unreadable.

Comment: Not sure about a specific way to do this other than suppressing clang-format for those lines i.e. `// clang-format off` & `// clang-format on`.

Comment: @bolov It felt a bit odd but it would have been okay however my vscode shows a redbar because of the improper identation in the second lines . See this image https://imgur.com/a/uJ3ZNk1

Comment: the vscode is the problem so fix the vscode, not the other way around. That is not normal behavior on the part of vscode. It's either a setting or an extension.

Comment: Okay I'll look into the extensions then. Thanks @bolov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using clang-format you should step away from the idea that your formatting is better than it's. Once you configured a style correctly, live with it and log bugs if there are changes that ain't correct.

In this case, `ColumnLimit` is the right thing to change. Depending on your screen, you might want to have a different value here. The number is the amount of characters that can be put on a single line (if tabs are replaced by spaces). If you exceed this number, it will always split.

Best you can do is to visualize this amount of characters by typing `#` 150 times. This can help you decide if the number is good enough or needs a change. Keep in mind that this limit is for all your code.

As already mentioned in comments, you can add `// clang-format off` to disable changes and `// clang-format on` to reenable formatting. However, this case ain't the right place to do so.

Comment: Thanks. I turned off the Indentation rainbow which was making it look odd and modified the column limit(column limit couldn't fix the issue) either way that was a pseudo code. I doubt I will use such long lines often as I'm just starting out.     Btw @JVApen I got the answer do I have to lock the question or something here ? I am a newbie at stackoverflow too

Comment: Depends, if your answer was in comments, feel free to put it in an answer with some more info and mark it as the answer (see V icon). If it's one of the existing answers, just mark that as the answer. If answers were useful you can upvote them (if you have the permission) without marking them the answer.